# How can I describe being a Youtube educator on my resume?

Tags: resume

I make YouTube videos on intermediate/advanced economic theory and would like to put it down on my resume.

What title can I use to describe this on my resume, other than "Educational Youtuber"?

Comment: What exactly do you believe is wrong with "Educational Youtuber" or "Youtube Educator"?

Comment: @Dukeling its a little informal IMO.

Comment: "Online Instructor"?

Comment: I would imagine you would also have a link to your youtube profile, right?

Comment: @bharal that would be the case.

Comment: what is the job you are going for and how does having an online platform help you apply for that job?

Comment: @bharal its a teaching position at a tutorial company near my university.

Comment: do you interact with your youtube students or have good reviews and comments on your youtube account?

Comment: Is it relevant? I mean, do people watch them? Because otherwise you better apply fora job making such videos and use them as example. Audience size matters. OTOH too many people and questions about why you need a job will come up.

Answer (score 2):

Not mentioning a specific company hosting the videos in the title can have the advantage of allowing you to transition the content over to another host without any justification added to the resume (taking Youtube as an example: accounts nowadays are closed for various reasons, videos become unavailable due to multiple conflicting interests and disputes seem to take a long time to produce a timely effect).

[DarkCygnus suggested a list of communities](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/115012/36840) to be added, but a **list of specific topics that you taught** and links to those videos in different online communities (with the date uploaded and fetched in parenthesis for reference) may actually be more direct and immediately useful for a recruiter. You are also showing no preference for any specific community (and you are backing up your content).

Regarding the title for your activity, besides the good options previously presented:

- Online Educator/Instructor

The following may also be considered:

1. **Online/Web Tutor**: since videos are used as individualized methods for teaching.
2. **Remote Tutor/Educator/Instructor**: since even if there was no website hosting your videos, you could send a copy of the videos to those requesting them and possibly make a business out of it (e.g. a private website or [Patreon](https://www.patreon.com) style with monthly subscriptions, possibly including direct calls).
3. **Educational Video Producer**: even though you may have no degree in the film industry, if you clearly demonstrate significant skills in the production of your videos and your audience grew due to this, this might be a suitable title.

There is actually a Wikipedia topic referring to these points:

> ## [Video production for distance education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_production#Video_production_for_distance_education)
>
> Video production for distance education is the process of capturing, editing, and presenting educational material specifically for use in on-line education. Teachers integrate best practice teaching techniques to create scripts, organize content, capture video footage, edit footage using computer based video editing software to deliver final educational material over the Internet. It differs from other types of video production in at least three ways:
>
> - It augments traditional teaching tools used in on-line educational programs.
> - It may incorporate motion video with sound, computer animations, stills, and other digital media.
> - Capture of content may include use of cell phone integrated cameras and extend to commercial high-definition Broadcast quality cameras.
>
> **The primary purpose of using video in distance education is to improve understanding and comprehension in a synchronous or asynchronous manner**.

Answer (score 1):

> What title can I use to describe this on my resume, other than "Educational Youtuber"?

As user @Roger suggested in [comments](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115000/how-can-i-describe-being-a-youtube-educator-on-my-resume#comment359293_115000), I'd say that a good alternative is to say **Online Instructor**, or **Online Educator**.

You could then list or mention the online communities you instruct at (YouTube and others you got). Including a link could be helpful so they can see your rating and your teaching style.

Seems that you are applying for a job related to teaching, so including this is a good idea. If it where other kind of job, where that experience were not too relevant, I suggest you leave it out in favor of other more relevant and attractive aspects of your profile with respect to that job.